# Copy local position of child object to a different child object

Tags: transforms, parent

So I have numerous copies of objects with long parent/child relationships. I want to add add and parent a new child at the end of each parent/child "list" at the same position ( essentially, I want to add a "hand" at the end of each "arm" ).

So, I can create and duplicate a hand, and parent them properly, but because each body is in a different location/rotation in the world. I have to MANUALLY move each hand to it's world location, because the little Transform Flyout doesn't show each hand in a local position/rotation viewpoint; it only cares about the world settings.

Every other program I've used shows that data in a local view...and all I would need to do is select all of the hands, and (for example) enter (1,2,3) in the position requester, and then all of the hands would just instantly move to a local offset position of (1,2,3) in relation to it's parent; Blender just moves all of the hands to world position of (1,2,3).

How do a do a "mass move" of setting a bunch of child objects to the same local offset positions from their parents?

Comment: Ctrl + P -> Set Parent To Object (Without Inverse)?  Is this the function you're looking for?

Comment: There is also ALT + P > Clear parent inverse if you want to reset the transform after the fact